# Returning an object with buffer handles from node extension

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js

When writing a node.js extension how do you safely return an object that has node::Buffer properties safely so they don't get garbage collected afterwards.

Code extract from my node-sodium library, a port of lib sodium to node.

```
#define NEW_BUFFER_AND_PTR(name, size) \
  Buffer* name = Buffer::New(size); \
  unsigned char* name ## _ptr = (unsigned char*)Buffer::Data(name)

Handle<Value> bind_crypto_sign_keypair(const Arguments& args) {
  HandleScope scope;

  NEW_BUFFER_AND_PTR(vk, crypto_sign_PUBLICKEYBYTES);
  NEW_BUFFER_AND_PTR(sk, crypto_sign_SECRETKEYBYTES);

  if( crypto_sign_keypair(vk_ptr, sk_ptr) == 0) {
    Handle<Object> result = Object::New();
    result->Set(String::NewSymbol("publicKey"), vk->handle_);
    result->Set(String::NewSymbol("secretKey"), sk->handle_);
    return scope.Close(result);
  }
  return scope.Close(Undefined());
}
```

This function creates a set of public and secret keys used for signing.
In Javascript I do

```
var keys = binding.crypto_sign_keypair();
console.out(keys.publicKey);
console.out(keys.secretKey);
```

This works, but sometimes garbage collection is run and the buffers become invalid, and all I get is a stack dump and a crash that starts with the output:

```
#
# Fatal error in ../deps/v8/src/api.h, line 297
# CHECK(allow_empty_handle || that != __null) failed
#


==== Stack trace ============================================

Security context: 0x2190c4706b71 <JS Object>#0#
```

any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: That main thing I see is `Handle<Object> result` should be `Local<Object> result`. Not an expert on this though.

Comment: Originally I had the Local<Object> result, but it wasn't working so using the Handle was an attempt at a fix. Unsuccessful at that. Thanks for the comment

Comment: Not working how? It definitely shouldn't be just `Handle<...>`.

Comment: Still giving me the Fatal error as with Local. Reverted back to Local